# Why does TypeScript not check imports for existence?

Tags: typescript

To my surprise, I've found that TypeScript doesn't check the existence of imports like this:

```
import 'nonexistent_path' // no error

require('nonexistent_path') // no error
```

This works, but my IDE (Webstorm) removes such imports as unused:

```
import {} from 'nonexistent_path' // error

import * as MyModule from 'nonexistent_path'  // error
```

I have many such imports, and I keep encountering errors when running the application. Are there any ways to solve this basic issue? Custom solutions are welcome. I'm wondering if my project structure might be incorrect. How else can I load any module that doesn't export anything?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41937

Comment: Not exactly about that, here's more precise https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20576

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution:

```js
export * from './nonexistent_path'
```

Then TypeScript will check the module for existence, the module will be compiled to js, and the IDE will not detect it as an unused import/export.